Why does Flutter take many times when the open project and after the command flutter pub get
I have been using Flutter for quite a long time, when I use it, I often experience a problem where when I open my Flutter project, the code takes a very long time to load.
You can see in the following photo that the color code is not the color it should be, and at the top right, under the word podfile, there is a blue line that indicates it is loading, and I can't click on the existing variables.
This happens quite often to me when I close the project and reopen it after a while and after running pub get or adding a new pub dev plugin using commands in the terminal.

This my flutter doctor

Has anyone experienced something like this, and what do you do so that this loading doesn't happen often or can make this project load faster?
Thank you

First of all, you have so many extensions that you do not need for this. Use VSCode profiles and disable the extensions you don't need. Second of all, you have 2000 issues, which either means extensions are doing something or you have a huge code base.
A lot more information is needed unfortunately.

Thank you for the information @vivideradicator. for 2000 The issue occurred because I had done Flutter clean, and after that, I ran Flutter Pub get, but it still had an error, and loading took a long time like in the photo.
